# Flutter Image.memory() ERROR Invalid image data

Tags: image, flutter, byte

I'm trying to dislpay image.memory but I'm getting an error as the following photo showing.

[image]

The bytes of image are the following.
[image]

UPDATE -1-

Below you see my code
[image]

[image]

UPDATE -2-
The result if snpashot.data is null or not
[image]

UPDATE -3-
The changes that i did to get the bytes direct. But also getting error
[image]

[image]

I can't explain it and I didn't find anythng solution for this error.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Post your code for Image.memory & variable which holds bytes.

Comment: I update it! Thank you!

Comment: can you confirm `snapshot.data` passed in memory is null or not?

Comment: Yes, I updated.

Comment: It seems bytes could be corrupted in `_getTripPictures`. Try rendering Image.memory with direct bytes output to confirm that once.

Comment: I tried and what I do is: I called the _getTripPictures to initState() and inside of the function I'm saving the base64Decode(valueImages[0]); to bytes and then the image.memory gets direct the byte variable but I'm getting a new error, i think it is because the widget builds first before the byte variable filled and the image.memory is null. Also if I use setState to fill the variable bytes with base64Decode(valueImages[0]); inside _getTripsPictures getting the same error plus this ---> Another exception was thrown: Exception: Invalid image data. SEE THE UPDATE -3-

Comment: I meant, just pass the list directly without any async calls..

Comment: How can I do that ? I should make async call to get the image bytes from my API node js

Comment: Only for testing purposes to verify whether data is corrupted or not. Just pass the actual value you're getting in `Image.memory`.

Comment: I parse the bytes manually but I'm stll getting error of Exception: Invalid image data. What I can do now ? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: I have the same problem. I think we have to encode image before pass to image memory. But I cannot find solutions

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the base64 that you're trying to load in the Image widget is invalid. Try debugging, look for base64 image samples, load it in the Image widget, and see if it renders fine. You can also [test encoding/decoding](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/image-base64) the image that you're using to see if it matches the decoded image using `base64Decode()`